# How to connect jira to power BI service and visualize

Tags: powerbi, jira, powerbi-desktop

I'm using power BI service inside an virtual machine. I want to connect to jira and whatever changes are made on any tickets, I need to capture in my power BI and visualize this.
Is this achievable?
how to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you need this to Power BI Service, use Dataflow, blank query, and enter this. However, it's gonna work from anywhere. So even Power BI Desktop Power Query.
Change things that are unique for your case such as `BaseUrl`, `JQL` or `Authentication`

```
let
  // Define the connection, JQL
  BaseUrl = "https://jira.yoursite.com",
  RelativePath = "/rest/api/2/search?",
  JQL = "jql=project=XXX",
  maxResults = "&maxResults=40",
  startAt = "&startAt=",

  // Save the records through paging
  initialRequest = (Web.Contents(BaseUrl,
            [RelativePath = RelativePath&JQL,
            // For authorization, generate JIRA token for your profile and place it into parameter called "token", in order to make this work, or simple replace the token with the string
            Headers=[Authorization="Bearer "& token]])),
  LoadJson = Json.Document(initialRequest),
  totalResults = LoadJson[total],
  IssuesThroughPaging = List.Generate( () => 0, each _ <= totalResults, each _ + 40, 
      each 
        let 
          Request = (Web.Contents(BaseUrl,
                [RelativePath = RelativePath&JQL&maxResults&startAt&Text.From(_),
                Headers=[Authorization="Bearer "& token]])),
          GetJson = Json.Document(Request),
          RetrieveIssues = GetJson[issues]
        in
          RetrieveIssues
      ),
     // Expand your lists 
  ExpandResult = List.Combine(List.Combine({IssuesThroughPaging})),
  // Expand Key Column
  GetKey = (ListOfIssues as list) =>
    let
      Keys = List.Transform(ListOfIssues, each Record.Field(_, "key"))
    in
      Keys,
  // Expand Fields
  GetFields = (ListOfIssues as list) =>
    let
      Fields = List.Transform(ListOfIssues, each Record.Field(_, "fields"))
    in
      Fields,
  // Call Key and Field functions
  AllKeys = GetKey(ExpandResult),
  AllFields = GetFields(ExpandResult),
  // Put Keys and Fields together
  CreateTable = Table.FromColumns({AllKeys, AllFields}, {"key", "Records"}),
  // Expand Needed Records
  ExpandFields = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(CreateTable, "Records", {"resolution", "lastViewed", "labels", "issuelinks", "assignee", "subtasks", "reporter", "issuetype", "project", "resolutiondate", "updated", "description", "summary", "duedate", "priority", "status", "creator", "created"}, {"resolution", "lastViewed", "labels", "issuelinks", "assignee", "subtasks", "reporter", "issuetype", "project", "resolutiondate", "updated", "description", "summary", "duedate", "priority", "status", "creator", "created"})
in
  ExpandFields
```

The paging is needed because JIRA returns only 50 rows per response, that's why there's function to gather the responses iteratively.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Vojtěch.
It works.
Only one error was with "Authorization". But replacing it with "Prefer" fix it.
[corrected parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSRF7.png)